# How to show that $ M_n(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}?$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show that $ M_n(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}?$

My attempt : Here $M_n(\mathbb{R})$  denotes  set pf all $n \times n$ real matrices

dim($M_n(\mathbb{R})=n^2$

But here  im confused  how  to show that $ M_n(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}?$

Comment: Isomorphic as what? Vector spaces?

Comment: @DuncanRamage you know that  I have tag linear algebra...Most probably vector space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that two finite-dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension are always isomorphic. Obviously, both given spaces have dimension $n^2$. We could show it by using bases of both spaces. For $M_n(\mathbb R)$ this could be matrices with one entry $1$ and the other entries $0$ (call them $b_i$). For $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ this could be the standard basis (call them $c_i$) . The map mapping $b_i$ to $c_i$ is an isomorphism.